# CSS stripes for titles from sides

Tags: html, css, drupal

I have this design that I have to code to HTML, but I got stuck on title section. This is what I want to do:

[image]

So when creating content with title, those stripes fits automatically according to the length of the title. Possible?

Comment: The solutions works great while border is 1px, my border is 7px thick and it becomes unaligned with text. How do I align a thicker border than 1px?

Comment: Hmm solved with position: relative; top: 2px; how do I select this question as answered?

Comment: You could always answer your questions. If you feel that it would be helpful for the others, post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

checkout this link , if this works fine for you Try This [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Vqjg/1/)

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/3Vqjg/]
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Vqjg/1/)

```
<div class="h-border">
  <div class="heading">
    <h2>About Me</h2>
  </div>
</div>

.h-border {
border-top: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.heading {
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
line-height: 40px;
text-align: center;
/*background-image: url(../img/cross-pattern.png);
background-repeat: repeat;*/
background: #f00;
}

h2 {
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 10px;
background:#fff;
width:30%;
display: inline;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you expanded your answer to explain the logic.